# ASP.NET Core MVC Select with dynamic searchig

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a Login page, and I want to implement when an user type the username for example "Jh", because he is called Jhon, then next to the Login form there is a selectlist, and listing all the usernames from the database that contains Jh, and it should be dynamic, I mean if the input changes then update the search automatically.

Here is my view

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-7">
    <form asp-action="Login">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
        {
            <span class="text-danger">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </span>
        }
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReturnUrl)
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="UserId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        @*<div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input asp-for="RememberLogin" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RememberLogin)
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>*@

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Bejelentkezés" class="btn btn-primary w-100" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select asp-for="UserId" asp-items="ViewBag.Users" size="6" multiple class="form-control"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

<script>
    $("#search_id").keyup(function () {
        //call ajax method
    });
</script>
```

Here is my controller (Im using stored procedures):

```
 public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl = "/")
    {
        LoginModel objLoginModel = new LoginModel();
        objLoginModel.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;

        string sqlQuery = "execute GetUsers";
        var result = _context.GetUsers(sqlQuery);
        ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(result, "UserId", "UserId");
        return View("Login");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I write a simple demo here without any third part plugin, It is a basic demo to show how to achieve dynamic search, You can refer and make some changes to meet the needs of your own project. I hople it is what you want.

**Model**

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Student

<input asp-for="@Model.Name" oninput="Search(this.value)"/>

<div id="result"></div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
       function Search(data) {
          var value ={
            "name": data    
          }
          
          $.post({
                url: 'https://localhost:7209/Home/Download1',
                ethod: 'Post',
                data: value,                               
                success: function (data) {
                    result = '';
                    for (var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
                        result = result +'<tr><td>'+data[i].id+'</td><td>'+data[i].name+'</td></tr>';
                    }  
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration dataTable" role="grid">'
                                                   +'<thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>'                                                                
                                                   +'<tbody>'+result+'</tbody>'
                                                   +'</table>';
                    
                }
          })
       }
    
    </script>
}
```

**Home/Download1**

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Download1(string name)
    {
        
        //For testing convenience, I just hard code here, you can change it and select data from database

        var result = Students.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name)).ToList(); 
        return Json(result);
    }
```

**Demo**

[image]

Comment: HI @kajahun123, If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Thanks.